# Double rounded corner

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]
As I can rounded the corner to fit both sides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the ***Bridge Edge Loops*** option. The subsurfed result'll be similar to the one achieved with beveling.
[image]

Select the same amount of vertices laying on the oposite sides, press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, type ***Bridge*** and click this option. In the *Tool Shelf* options (<kbd>T</kbd>) change the *number of cuts* to fit the edge loops' number. Then unselect the top vertices (<kbd>C</kbd>, hold <kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd>) and select only bottom ones (<kbd>C</kbd>). Hit <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles* and increase the *merge distance*. Fill the hole with diamond quads (select vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd>).
[image]

Comment: The beveled edges result is the correct way, Bridge edge loops result leaves bad topology and is not round properly. So I like half the answer and the other half I dislike, but will leave an upvote for the good stuff:)

Comment: Haha, you're right :). It may not be perfect. The best way could be doing it (beveling) from scratch or creating the exact portion of mesh (beveling other mesh with the same parameters) to fill the hole. Maybe you have an idea what other method to use to fill it perfectly?