# Is there a way to solve terminator artifacts?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Has anyone found a way to fix the problem?
Increasing the subdivisions the artifacts remains, less visible because the polygons are smaller.
I have also attached Arnold image (Redshift is very similar) even with less subdivisions and more contrast that work better.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66607/double-rounded-corner

Comment: It does not seem the same problem. I used a simple cube with the subdivision modifier.
I've read that it is a known problem, in Mental Ray was resolved many years ago, Renderman may still have this problem.
I would like to see if there is a way to fix it in the latest version of Blender 2.79.

Comment: Which renderer?

Comment: Artifacts in Cycles render

Answer (score 3):

From blender 2.90, you can tweak this using the Object's [Shadow Terminator Offset](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/object_settings/object_data.html#shading) Shading property.

[image: Shadow Terminator Effect]

Answer (score 2):

Terminator artifacts are a [complicated topic](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4986/ray-tracing-shadows-the-shadow-line-artifact) of raytracing. From a technical point of view the normal of the face shows the way from the light source. Therefore the face is not illuminated by light and a shadow is cast at the [right place](http://wiki.povray.org/content/Knowledgebase:The_Shadow_Line_Artifact).
Even if it is technically expected behavior and does not mean a "bug" - from the user's point of view this is often not the desired effect of *smooth shading*.

[image]

Source: [wiki.povray.org](http://wiki.povray.org/content/Knowledgebase:The_Shadow_Line_Artifact)

Simple measures to **work around** the problem are:

- More geometry through subdevision
- or create the normals with a high resolution mesh and back to the low res mesh
- large area lighting

Some render engines work around this problem in different ways. Requests for solution of this problem are in the bugtracker for a [while](https://developer.blender.org/T37814) now. current information can be found [here](https://developer.blender.org/T68920).