# Face smooth rendering in cycles without using Subsurf?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Perhaps this goes against the function of cycles on some philosophical level, but I must ask anyway...

Do I have to subsurf my model to get rid of the hard shadows between faces? If so, the subsurf must be rather high (like 3).

I'd much rather the face smoothing of the model itself be observed rather than forcing hard edges.

Any advice on this?

In the example provided, you can see face-edges that are otherwise smooth in viewport (and game engines). Subdividing removes the spiky-ness of the spikes...so that is the conundrum.

---

EXAMPLE

[image]

Comment: Could you show us some examples?

Comment: Give me a moment to render some...

Comment: Example provided.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92619/is-there-a-way-to-solve-terminator-artifacts