# Weird faces on retopologized mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

does anybody know what could be causing these artefacts?

So far i have tried different render engines, using cage/no cage to bake, trying different uv seams, adding more detail, but to no avail...

!!!EDIT: so I figured it has nothing to do with baking aspect, the weird faces still persist even when no normal map or material is applied.

Here is the file with retopologized version: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XBZLTh7mD5iP6_waT2Md6tGEbInlzMxI/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

[image: Without normal map applied. Just base mesh.]

Comment: do you select option non-color data?

Comment: @Crantisz, Yes I did, but check the edited question, since I figured it has nothing to do with normal map.

Comment: Hm, it's looks like a [terminator problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92619/is-there-a-way-to-solve-terminator-artifacts) - try to make lights bigger. If it doesn't help,  can you provide a (part of) the file?

Comment: @Crantisz Ok I included the file. Increasing lights size seems to do something but it doesn't solve the problem I'm afraid.

Comment: @Crantisz It might in fact be the problem in lights size as the model doesn't appear to have those problems in Unity environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's definitely terminator problem. It's one of "problems" of Cycles render. To avoid it, you should  make lights bigger or/and add some subdivisions on model.

No artifacts with subsurf at level 1:
[image]

But if you want to export it to Unity, this problem doesn't appear in it. It's a problem of ray-traced renderes.