# Strange artifacts

Tags: modeling, artifacts

I imported a model but after i set the materials, these strange artifact appeared and the lighting seems wrong.
I tried to recalculate the normals, disable/enable the autosmooth and other things but none of this worked. Someone have any ideas?[image: artifact]
EDIT:
Enabling soft shadows make the artifacts less visible but the problem still persist, moreover I think that this is only diffusing and softening the shadows without removing the issue.
[image: soft shadows enabled]
blender version: 2.8
sorry for my bad english

Comment: maybe try Properties > Data > Geometry Data, click Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this didn't work.

Comment: maybe share a part of your object on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The site continue to give me "error uploading", so i cannot share the object

Comment: I uploaded the file in a google drive folder:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t1Cf91QPQqC3gIsDUM38B0135K_MdsHL?usp=sharing

Comment: Read: [How to avoid terminator artifacts while still using smooth shading?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p) and [how to solve terminator artifacts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92619/is-there-a-way-to-solve-terminator-artifacts) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139205/normal-map-bad-shading-in-rendered-display and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/cycles-shadows-on-smooth-shaded-mesh-strange-behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid terminator artifacts while still using smooth shading and the new pointiness attribute?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to enable is the "Soft Shadows" setting under the render settings tab in the shadows dropdown.

Below I have a model with a similar issue with the shadows looking really jagged and bad:

[image: bad shadow]

Then, I turn on 'Soft Shadows' (seen on the right), and it looks much better:

[image: good shadow]

I am not 100% sure that this is your problem, but it might, be, so I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer;
this reduced the problem but it's still visible,soft shadows don't resolve the issue, simply make it less apparent