# Shading on model not correct

Tags: modeling, mesh, lighting, shadows

I can't seem to get the shading on this model correct.

**Model settings:**

- Edge Split
- Subdivision surface- 3 subdivisions
- Of course smooth shading ON
- Model was based on circle with 120 vertices.

My question is how can I get a better result?

[image]

Here you can see the shading is not right.

[image]

Comment: Auto- Smooth is on. The model was based on a circle with 120 verticies.

Comment: yes my remark was stupid, could you please share your file (at least one cylinder)?

Comment: The model itself looks not smooth enough. Looks like a product of Subdivision made in Edit mode rather then Subdivision Surface modifier, which gives flat faces instead of smooth curve all along the circle. That can be an optic illusion, but that's the first thing the look of it brings to mind. Second reason could be Bump/Normal map, another can be wrong edge split settings, which would "cut" the mesh on too wide angles.

Comment: it looks like you have subdivided with a simple W > Subdivide (not Subdivide Smooth) which has added additional edge loops but not smoothed the existing edge loops

Comment: I think it is another case of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/some-areas-of-the-mesh-are-dark/91916#91916 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92619/is-there-a-way-to-solve-terminator-artifacts

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The problem was indeed subdividing in edit mode. Problem solved.