# Weird triangulated shadows in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

[image]There are those triangulated shadows on my object in the rendered viewport and in the render,I use a sun as a lamp.How to avoid those weird triangles?

Comment: Your light is very sharp, you can see the shadows cast by the individual polygons even though it's shaded smooth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some areas of the mesh are dark](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/some-areas-of-the-mesh-are-dark)

Comment: This is a [terminator artefact](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/92619/35559), so although you wouldn't fairly know it, the question has been asked before. The issue will be partly got-around in 2.9.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982

Comment: I have already used Smooth shading and increased te polygon count but the problem is still there